# Create a draggable table and save weights

Tags: 8, forms

I'm struggling a bit with creating a draggable table.

I want to have a table that lists node labels, where it's possible to rearrange the order of the nodes. The new weights shall be available when I submit the form.

This is my code so far:

```
$rows = [];
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $weight = $node->weight;

  $row = [
    'weight' => $weight,
    $node->label(),
  ];

  $rows[] = [
    'data' => $row,
    'class' => ['draggable'],
    '#weight' => $weight,
  ];

  $form['table'][$node->id()]['weight'] = [
    '#type' => 'weight',
    '#title' => t('Weight'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#default_value' => $weight,
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => [
        'draggable-weight'
      ]
    ],
  ];
}

$form['table'] = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => [
    $this->t('Weight'),
    $this->t('Title'),
  ],
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#attributes' => [
    'id' => 'my-module-table'
  ],
  '#tabledrag' => [[
    'action' => 'order',
    'relationship' => 'sibling',
    'group' => 'draggable-weight',
  ]],
];
```

When I `kint($form_state->getValues())` in my submit handler `table` is equals to `''`.

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but the lack of documentation for this makes it hard to find out.

Comment: Aren't you setting a load of things up with `$form['table'][$node->id()]['weight']` but then all of that is lost because you're redefining `$form['table']` in the next bit as `$form['table'] = [` so anything previously set in the `$form['table']` is gone

Comment: Nice catch, now it saves the values, but I can't drag any more.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/weight - Did you check this module? It does exactly that

Comment: This is a part of Drupal core, it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help from @Leigh I found the problem. I was setting some keys on `$form['table'][$node->id()]` and then overriding `$form['table'][$node->id()]` at the bottom.

I have moved a bit around in the code and now it works perfectly.

```
$form['table'] = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => [
    '',
    $this->t('Weight'),
    $this->t('Title'),
  ],
  '#attributes' => [
    'id' => 'my-module-table'
  ],
  '#tabledrag' => [[
    'action' => 'order',
    'relationship' => 'sibling',
    'group' => 'draggable-weight',
  ]],
];

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $weight = $node->weight;

  $form['table'][$node->id()] = [
    'data' => [],
  ];
  $form['table'][$node->id()]['#attributes']['class'] = ['draggable'];
  $form['table'][$node->id()]['weight'] = [
    '#type' => 'weight',
    '#title' => t('Weight'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#default_value' => $weight,
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => [
        'draggable-weight'
      ]
    ],
  ];
  $form['table'][$node->id()]['label'] = [
    '#markup' => $node->label(),
  ];
}
```